# Why are my succulents getting powdery and black?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, succulents

This is an Echeveria Blue Blush Succulent:

[image]

I've got it in on a window sill where it gets good natural light (as much as you can get in December in NY State, anyway), and I think I'm watering correctly (rarely, and then a good soak), and it's in the succulent soil that was provided by the grower, and yet it's still doing this.

What am I doing wrong / how do I fix this?

Comment: Does the pot have drainage?

Comment: There's about a dime sized hole in the bottom of the pot.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert but that looks a lot like powdery mildew to me.  I've done some Googling and this does appear to be a thing on Echeveria.   You can get sprays to kill powdery mildew.  (There are also natural remedies like dish soap). https://gardenswhisper.com/powdery-mildew-on-succulents/ goes through a list of things you can do

https://www.reddit.com/r/plantclinic/comments/15knite/is_this_mildew_on_my_echeveria_if_so_how_do_i/ talks about using a copper fungicide pray and has a picture of an infected plant - although not as bad as yours.

Are you also able to reduce the humidity ?